# R NaN value only appear when using variable in calculation

Tags: r, nan

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/txl9C.png)
As the screenshot shows, it works if I manually break down the original equation; otherwise, the result will be a NaN value. This one issue really bothers me since I recently have many R errors on the sample codes given in the course, leading to a trust issue between me and R.

I tired to roundup the value  of the first bracket and assign it to another variable before I conduct the power of 1/3. However, the value of mu still shows NaN in this case.
e.g.
`m = roundup(((2*s3/(pi - 4))), 9)`
`mu = m^(1/3)`